# Post content manipulation with substr_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, post, replace

Good day EB!
I am a php newbie and am stuck with some simple task.

I want to insert a string after 5th fullstop into post content. However, I am still stuck with first step of writing the substitution. Afterwards, I will add counting to $pos.
I tried with substr_replace() as well.

Here is my code in my function.php file of my theme.

```
function replace_content($content)
{
    $oldstr = $content;
    $str_to_insert = "tst";
    $pos = 30;
    $new_content = substr($oldstr, 0, $pos) . $str_to_insert . substr($oldstr, $pos);


    return $new_content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Its not returning the expected result.
Thank you for suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if there are any in-build method exists. But, there is workaround for your problem

You could use `explode` and loop together

```
$array = array(".",$content); //split by fullstop and store it in array
$new_content = ""
$str_to_insert = "tst";
$count=1

foreach($array as $value) { // loop through the array now
  if($count==5)
   {
   $new_content = $new_content.$value.$str_to_insert."."; // insert string on fifth occurrence 
   }
  else
  {
  $new_content = $new_content.$value."."; // otherwise just append string as it was
  }
 $count++;
}
```

Comment: I think you missed st. $new_content is not defined!? I tested it. It places string_to_insert before or after content.if($count==1) or if($count==2) meanwhile content has more than 2.

Comment: Yep, 10x. Its good idea, but not working really. Why do you have $new_content = "" blank? Shouldnt be the array inside it?

Comment: That was initialize with nothing. What do you mean by not working. Could you share the output and expected output using my code.?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use just the explode function to add the string after the fifth occurrence of '.'. For example you can use the following function:

```
function replace_content($content)
{
    $str_to_insert = "tst";
    $pos = 5;

    $data = explode(".", $content);
    $data[5] = $str_to_insert . " " . $data[5];
    $new_content = implode(".", $data);

    return $new_content;
}
```